# How do I fix the mql4 error "array out of range"?

Tags: mql4

I am trying to add an indicator code. While everything compiles just fine, the terminal shows the error, "array out of range".
This is the code that reads the price data from the .csv file and draws it as an indicator on the current chart.
The .csv file contains three months' price data in the form of 1 minute period.

`#property indicator_buffers 1
#property indicator_color1 White
double ExtMapBuffer1[];
bool Calculated=false;
extern datetime endDateTime=D'2021.03.31 05:59:00';
int init()
{
    SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE,0,1);
    SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtMapBuffer1);

    return(0);
}

int start()
{
    int  i,counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
    if (!Calculated)
    {
        double PriceArray[24*60*30*1];   **//issue1**
        string lastDT = endDateTime;   
        if (!ReadCSVToArray(PriceArray,lastDT,fileName,"","\n")) Print("Reading file error: ",GetLastError());
        int bars=ArraySize(PriceArray);
        int firstBar = iBarShift(symbolName,PERIOD_M1,endDateTime);   
        ExtMapBuffer1[bars+firstBar-1]=PriceArray[0];   **//error1: array out of range**
        for (i=2;i<=bars;i++) 
        {
            ExtMapBuffer1[bars+firstBar-i]=PriceArray[i-1];
        }
        for (i=firstBar-1;i>=0;i--) 
        {
            ExtMapBuffer1[i]=0;
        }
        
        Calculated=true;
    }
        
    return(0);
}`

issue1: If I set the size of PriceArray as a big value for 3 month's data, such as 24*60*30*3, I could meet the compile error: "local variables is larger than 512KB"
error1: If the size of PriceArray is small, the compiling is fine but running error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly read a csv's of variable or unknown length, you should use the first dimension of the array for your rows and the second dimension for your columns. You would therefore have an array statement of `string data[1][5];` for a csv which contained date/O/H/L/C for example.

You can then resize your array as you loop through reading your csv file as follows:

```
int handle=FileOpen(FileName,FILE_CSV|FILE_READ,",");
if(handle==INVALID_HANDLE) Print("Error opening file ",GetLastError());
else
{
   int row=0;
   while(!FileIsEnding(handle))
   {
      if(row>0) ArrayResize(data,row+1);
      //carry out array reading here
      data[row][0]=FileReadString(handle); //date
      data[row][1]=FileReadString(handle); //open
      data[row][2]=FileReadString(handle); //high
      data[row][3]=FileReadString(handle); //low
      data[row][4]=FileReadString(handle); //close
      row++;
   }
   FileClose(handle);
}
```

Note, you can not resize the 2nd dimension of a multi dimensional array so this dimension must match the structure of your csv file.